# Consecutive sentence, same citation: Chicago date-author style

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style

I am writing a paper in which I repeat a newspaper article citation.

"The New York Times article discusses the introduction of the AFB mainframe computer (Stevens, 1984). During an interview with a salesman, the AFB is called a "revolutionary tool" (????)."

Should I use the year, or the author's last name, or a different information, in the second, bolded citation?

I would like to avoid using "ibid.".

Thank you!